# Does the basis have to be orthogonal for a vector to be projected onto it?

Tags: linear-algebra

A vector $\mathbf{v}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be projected onto a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with an *orthogonal* basis {$\mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_2,...,\mathbf{u}_k$} with the formula:
$\overline{\mathbf{v}} = \text{proj}_{\mathcal{U}}(\mathbf{v}) = p_1\mathbf{u}_1 + p_2\mathbf{u}_2 + ... + p_k\mathbf{u}_k$

where

$p_i = \frac{\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{u}_i}{\|\mathbf{u}_i\|^2}$, $1 \leq i \leq k$.

But is it generally required that the subspace for which $\mathbf{v}$ is going to be projected onto has an *orthogonal* basis? Can't $\mathbf{v}$ be projected onto any subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, not necerally one with an *orthogonal* basis?

Comment: Indeed, all you need to describe a projection (i.e., a linear map $P$ with $P^2=P$) is the target subspace and any complement of it ...  It appears however that the goal is to describe the *orthogonal* projection to the subspace.

Comment: are you familiar with the notion of direct sums of subspaces? i.e if $V$ and $W$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R^n}$, do you know what a statement like: $\mathbb{R^n} = V \oplus W$ means?

Answer (score 0):

*All* subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$ have an orthogonal basis, which can be derived from an arbitrary basis by the Gram–Schmidt process. Therefore, vectors can be projected onto any subspace of $\mathbb R^n$, and the orthogonal basis requirement is just to make the calculations simpler.

Comment: Ahh okay, but so the formula can be modified to be applicable for *any* basis?

Comment: @FacPam Rather, you first derive an orthogonal basis, then apply the formula.

Comment: But you say "... and the orthogonal basis requirement is just to make the calculations simpler" - so I would just like to know, does this mean that, in theory,  the formula can be modified to be applicable for any basis?

Comment: @FacPam No. You must have an orthogonal basis, but it always exists.

Comment: Then it cannot be true that "and the orthogonal basis requirement is just to make the calculations simpler" - if you now the that the orthogonality requirement is not just to make the calculations simple but a general requirement for projecting $\mathbf{v}$?

Comment: @FacPam The modification of the projection formula _is_ the prior derivation of an orthogonal basis.

Comment: There's no need to compute an orthonormal basis first, the inverse of the Gram-Matrix of the basis will do.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Fine then.

Comment: @FacPam There’s a _different_ formula when the basis isn’t orthogonal, although it could be loosely considered to be a modification of the one you’ve got.